# Vue.js - can't store this.$route.params.id in variable at data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameters, routes, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js 3. I have here a simple code for routing and sending parameters.

Here is my Home.vue page

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>
      All Destinations
    </h1>
    <div class="destinations">
      <div v-for="destination in destinations" :key="destination.name">
        <router-link
          :to="{ name: 'DestinationDetails', params: { id: destination.id } }"
        >
          <h2>{{ destination.name }}</h2>
        </router-link>
        <figure>
          <router-link
            :to="{ name: 'DestinationDetails', params: { id: destination.id } }"
          >
            <img
              :src="require(`@/assets/${destination.image}`)"
              :alt="destination.name"
            />
          </router-link>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import store from "@/store.js";
export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      destinations: store.destinations
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.home {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.destinations {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.vue-school-active-class {
  color: #ab26ab;
}
</style>
```

Here is just a router link to DestinationDetails page and sending params
**id: destination.id**

Here is my DestinationDetails page

```
<template>
  <section >
     
    <h1>
      {{ destination.name }}
    </h1>
    <div class="destination-details">
      <img
        :src="require(`@/assets/${destination.image}`)"
        :alt="destination.name"
      />
      <p>{{destination.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import store from "@/store";

export default {
    
  data() {
    return {
      destinationId:this.$route.params.id
    };
  },

  computed: {
    destination() {
        return store.destinations.find(
        destination => destination.id === this.destinationId
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
img {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.destination-details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
p {
  margin: 0 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

I have a problem here when I'm using this code. The problem is here, I can't store my id from the route in **destinationId** variable.

I tried just to read the route id on page with blank template, just  tag and simple code
`<h1> Route: {{this.$route.params.id}} </h1>`  and everything works fine. I just can't store to this.$route.params.id in destinationId variable. Can someone explain me why this not working?

Here is my store.js file

```
export default {
  destinations: [
    {
      name: "Brazil",
      slug: "brazil",
      image: "brazil.jpg",
      id: 1,
      description:
        "all about Brazil, suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis.",
      experiences: [
        {
          name: "Iguaçu Falls",
          slug: "iguacu-falls",
          image: "iguacu-falls.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Pão de Açúcar",
          slug: "pao-de-acucar",
          image: "pao-de-acucar.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Sao Paulo",
          slug: "sao-paulo",
          image: "sao-paulo.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Salvador",
          slug: "salvador",
          image: "salvador.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Panama",
      slug: "panama",
      image: "panama.jpg",
      id: 2,
      description:
        "all about panama. Nam fermentum, leo ac lobortis tincidunt, justo felis semper nisi, sed facilisis quam ante a justo. Nam pulvinar nibh nec mi vestibulum cursus quis eget orci. Aenean faucibus faucibus ex, a imperdiet nibh luctus faucibus. Mauris porttitor, velit ac eleifend mattis, sem justo accumsan odio, ut mattis nulla nulla eu nibh. Cras justo risus, sollicitudin eget nulla a, consequat convallis tortor. Fusce eget neque metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla facilisi. Sed aliquam nunc id lectus sagittis, ac elementum eros egestas. Aliquam sed tempor dui.",
      experiences: [
        {
          name: "Panama City",
          slug: "panama-city",
          image: "panama-city.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Panama Canal",
          slug: "panama-canal",
          image: "panama-canal.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Bocas del Toro",
          slug: "bocas-del-toro",
          image: "bocas-del-toro.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Santa Catalina",
          slug: "santa-catalina",
          image: "santa-catalina.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Hawaii",
      slug: "hawaii",
      image: "hawaii.jpg",
      id: 3,
      description:
        "all about hawaii. Etiam iaculis, ex in semper fringilla, lorem augue maximus lorem, in aliquet ex massa non enim. Maecenas pharetra orci eu semper pharetra. Suspendisse vel elit semper, fringilla metus ac, pulvinar justo. Vestibulum nibh lacus, pellentesque non arcu vel, efficitur eleifend lorem. Duis ultrices bibendum orci, nec laoreet elit. In vulputate massa vel massa cursus gravida. Aliquam sed lacus pulvinar, imperdiet risus at, lacinia dolor. Maecenas pellentesque arcu mattis iaculis efficitur. Maecenas quis sem pulvinar, sodales neque eget, efficitur odio.",
      experiences: [
        {
          name: "Na Pali Coast",
          slug: "na-pali-coast",
          image: "na-pali-coast.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "O'Ahu's North Shore",
          slug: "ohaus-north-shore",
          image: "ohaus-north-shore.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Waikiki Beach",
          slug: "waikiki-beach",
          image: "waikiki-beach.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Kilauea Volcano",
          slug: "kilauea-volcano",
          image: "kilauea-volcano.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Jamaica",
      slug: "jamaica",
      image: "jamaica.jpg",
      id: 4,
      description:
        "all about jamaica. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis.",
      experiences: [
        {
          name: "Tower Isle",
          slug: "tower-isle",
          image: "tower-isle.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Blue Mountain",
          slug: "blue-mountain",
          image: "blue-mountain.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Montego Bay",
          slug: "montego-bay",
          image: "montego-bay.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        },
        {
          name: "Port Antonio",
          slug: "port-antonio",
          image: "port-antonio.jpg",
          description:
            "Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis. Suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor. Cras eleifend ante sed arcu interdum, in bibendum enim ultricies. Integer rutrum quis risus at tempor. Maecenas facilisis, nisi vel pellentesque maximus, lectus felis malesuada purus, a pulvinar elit est quis turpis. Duis convallis purus quis finibus consequat. Pellentesque faucibus tincidunt augue non consequat. Donec fringilla at est sit amet blandit. Nunc at porttitor ligula. Fusce sed odio turpis."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

`$route.params` returns `String` as default where as your `id` in `store.js` is `Number`.

Therefore

```
 destination => destination.id === this.destinationId
```

will never find the result.

A fixed could be changing the type of your `id` or by changing strict compare `===` to `==` to not type check.

Or you could just convert your `id` into `String`

```
destination => destination.id === String(this.destinationId)
```

Comment: Crystal clear & succinct. Nice job!